# C# Charting - How to prevent auto refresh for AddXY Method

Tags: c#, winforms, events, charts

I have a windows forms application with a chart.

```
private System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart myChart;
```

Whenever I add points to that chart with:

```
myChart.Series[0].Points.AddXY(x, y);
```

the chart updates and respectivly also raises an event.

I don't want to update the chart upon adding data points automatically. I would rather have to do it by myself with

```
myChart.Update();
```

Is there any way to prevent the automatic update? (e.g. Using a different method or prevent the update within AddXY or something else)

Thanks and all the best in advance

Tim